# Simplifying $\cos(2\arcsin(x))$ using only pythagorean trigonometric identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, absolute-value

I know that one can simplify $\cos(2\arcsin(x))$ using $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cdot\cos(b)-\sin(a)\cdot\sin(b)$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\cos(2\arcsin(x))&=\cos^2(\arcsin(x))-\sin^2(\arcsin(x))
\\&=1-2\sin^2(\arcsin(x))
\\&=1-2x^2
\end{alignat}

---

I tried to make this simplification using only $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\cos^2(2\arcsin(x))&=1-\sin^2(2\arcsin(x))
\\ \left|\cos(2\arcsin(x))\right|&=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(2\arcsin(x))}
\\ &=\sqrt{1-\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}
\\ &=\sqrt{1-4x^2 |1-x^2|}
\\ &=\sqrt{1-4x^2(1-x^2)}
\\ &=\sqrt{1-4x^2+4x^4}
\\ &=\sqrt{\left(2x^2-1\right)^2}
\\ &=|2x^2-1|
\end{alignat}
And then I could not figure out how to proceed. So, how to get rid of $|\cdot|$ in:
$$\left|\cos(2\arcsin(x))\right|=|2x^2-1|$$
and get $1-2x^2$ ?

---

Note: this is a part of my attempt to solve the integral $\int x^2\cdot\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\,\mathrm dx$ by trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, we know
$$
\cos(2\sin^{-1}x) = \pm(2x^2-1).
$$
Since both these functions are continuous, we can just check one value in each region where $2x^2-1 > 0$ and $2x^2-1 < 0$ to verify the sign to use in that region. For $|x|<1/\sqrt{2}$, check $x = 0$, and for $|x|>1/\sqrt{2}$, check $x = \pm 1$. You'll find they all work out to $\cos(2\sin^{-1}x) = 1-2x^2$.

Comment: I have a question: If i have an equation like, for example, $\left| {\frac{1}{2}z + 4} \right| = \left| {4z - 6} \right|$, I don't need to check regions. Why do I need to do it in this case and in my example I don't?

Comment: In that equation, you're looking for a particular value of $z$. In this equation, you need it to be true for *every* value of $x$.

Comment: So is it really necessary to check more than one region? If we're talking about an identity, I think it is a contradiction to have an "piecewise identity", so checking only one region already gives me the identity, or am I wrong?

Comment: You have to check it because when the function goes through zero, continuity no longer guarantees the signs match. As a simple example, it's certainly true that $|x| = \pm x$, but for $x < 0$, $|x| = -x$, while for $x > 0$, $|x| = +x$.

Comment: But $|x|=\pm x$ is an equation, not an identity, while $\left|\cos(2\arcsin(x))\right|=|2x^2-1|$ is an identity. That is why I am in doubt, how can I have an "piecewise identity", in which I need to check every region, if by definition an identity is true for every value of x?

Comment: $|\cos(2\sin^{-1}x)| = |2x^2-1|$ is an identity, but it's not the one you're trying to prove. You're trying to prove $\cos(2\sin^{-1}x) = 1-2x^2$ *using* that identity, which requires you to check if the signs work out. In principle you'd have to check every $x$, but because the functions are continuous, you only need to check one value in each region between sign changes of one of the functions.

Comment: I think now I get it. Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos(2\arcsin x)$ will be $\ge0,$ if

$-\dfrac\pi2\le2\arcsin x\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\iff -\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\le x\le\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

In that case $$|2x^2-1|=-(2x^2-1)$$

Check if $x>\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

or $x<-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

Comment: But if $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, then $\frac{-\pi}{2}\leq \arcsin(x) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. And so $-\pi \leq 2 \arcsin(x) \leq \pi$?

Comment: @ViniciusACP, Yes, what's the confusion?

Comment: I misinterpreted it. Now I think I get it: I have three "intervals of evaluation" (obtained by making $\cos(2\arcsin(x))=0$ and $2x^2-1=0$). 
$$x<-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,|\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\le x\le\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,|\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x>\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$$
In the first, I have:
$$-\cos(2\arcsin(x))=+(2x^2-1)$$
In the second:
$$+\cos(2\arcsin(x))=-(2x^2-1)$$
In the third:
$$-\cos(2\arcsin(x))=+(2x^2-1)$$